# Css - set overflow: hidden on container of floated elements

Tags: html, css

Why if that root element `.wrapper` has `overflow: hidden` and `width:100px`, it still shows all three `.item` elements? I wanted to show just one (first of them) and hide others, but underlying, the `.item` must be in same row, so i can animate sliding.

SORRY, EDITED JSFIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/QpdY9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="itemWrapper">
            <div class="item a"></div>
            <div class="item b"></div>
            <div class="item c"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.item {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}

.itemWrapper{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.a {
    background-color: red;
}

.b {
    background-color: blue;
}

.c {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: It is working as you said... [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/harsh_shah/v26Gz/) So what do you want help for?

Comment: @HarshShah: check that jsfiddle link

Comment: @Krab.. Please check the fiddle link i have provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your jsfiddle

```
html, body, div {box-sizing: border-box; padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}; <-- that ; invalidates your next .wrapper class. If you remove it everything is fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

On your fiddle link, delete the last ";" on the first line. It will work fine.